# How to check sources who join my channel on Telegram?

Tags: hyperlink, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a Telegram channel and I share links on YouTube, Facebook, blogs and other sites. So my question is how to know from what source the user joined?

Please help me to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For that you'll need to use URL shortening services like [cutt.ly](https://cutt.ly), that provides analytics on visiting generated URLs. So you can generate and share them instead of direct URLs.

Also, you can add/implement similar functionality to your blog site and track [UTM-labels](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/campaign-url-builder/) together with others (that you probably use) in service like Google Analytics.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way because when you share anywhere your channel path stays fixed, telegram doesn't support that.

Comment: Telegram don't, but there are ways how to implement that, see my answer for details.